# LMMSE additive noise proof problem

Tags: statistics

Let X be a random variable with mean µ and variance 
$σ^2$
.
Consider an additive noise observation model of the form

$Y_i = X + W_i$
, for i = 1, . . . , n

where the observation errors $W_i$ are random variables with mean 0 and variance $λ_1^2
$
. Assume that the random variables $X, W_1, . . . , W_n$ are independent. Verify
that the linear minimum mean square error (LMMSE) estimator of X given
the observations $Y_1, . . . , Y_n$ is of the form

[click here to see the photo of the image of the form to prove, it was too long to format:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noF7D.png)

I'm very lost on how to start with this problem. If anyone could help, I would be very thankful!